# pgfplots - x unit with siunitx

Tags: pgfplots, siunitx

I want to use x unit=something to draw the units to an axis. In the manual I find this to use siunitx to do so:

```
\pgfplotsset{
  unit code/.code 2 args={\si{#1#2}}
}
```

Now I make a plot:

```
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel = \(E\),
    x unit={\mega\electronvolt.m}
  ]
```

The dot is written, which should not be. Manually, this works:

```
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel = \(E\),
    x unit=\si{\mega\electronvolt.m}
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're mixing the literal (`MeV.m`) and "interpreted"  (`\mega\electronvolt\m`) input modes of `siunitx`, which for some reason doesn't work in the `x unit` code. If you stick with the interpreted mode, so say `x unit={\mega\electronvolt\m}`, the output is correct. Also note that you should probably be using `\pgfplotsset{unit code/.code={\si{\@secondoftwo#1}}}` as Joseph Wright explains at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12135/make-pgfplots-typeset-axis-units-as-reciprocals-using-siunitx.

Comment: Ok, indeed it works with the interpreted input mode. Only using (and not mixing as I did) literal does't work either. So my question reduces to a question of convenience! I just like to use the literal, if that is not possible, so it is.

Comment: We'll have to wait for Joseph Wright to find this question, he might have a way of using literal input in this context. I would recommend using interpreted input anyway, though, because only that opens up all the nice features `siunitx` offers. If you don't use it, you might as well just type `MeV\,m` without using `siunitx` at all and get the same output.

Comment: NO! You should rather enjoy lunch :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is that `pgfplots` passes the unit 'wrapped up' inside some code. To get it out correctly here we have to take steps to expand it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,siunitx}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
  unit code/.code 2 args=
    \begingroup
    \protected@edef\x{\endgroup\si{#2}}\x
} 
\makeatother 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
  xlabel = \(E\),
  x unit=\mega\electronvolt.m]
\addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can do the same with `\expandafter` but you need a lot of them!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,siunitx}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\pgfplotsset{
  unit code/.code 2 args=
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\si
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{#2}%
} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
  xlabel = \(E\),
  x unit=\mega\electronvolt.m]
\addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The reason you have to force expansion is that unlike numbers, `siunitx` does not try to expand units: it expects them to be given 'as is'. As such, the search-and-replace for `.` fails as it's 'hidden' inside a `pgfplots` macro.